# Basic question related to dimension of intersection of two varities

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ and $W$ be irreducible varieties in $\mathbb{C}^n$. I have learned that intersection $V \cap W$ satisfies the following:
$$
codim \ V + codim \ W \geq codim \ V \cap W. 
$$
I was wondering if someone could possibly tell me if this relation holds 
even when $V$ and $W$ are algebraic sets not necessarily irreducible. In other words if $V$ and $W$ are algebraic sets (not necessarily irreducible), does it still hold that
$$
codim \ V + codim \ W \geq codim \ V \cap W? 
$$

I am guessing that it should hold, but I wasn't quite sure. I would appreciate any input! Thank you very much!

Comment: Does dimension necessarily make sense for a reducible variety?

Comment: @TedShifrin You should post that as an answer, so people looking for questions with 0 answers would not spend time on it before seeing your comment.

Comment: @Alex I don't think it's an answer. Dimension makes sense here!

Comment: @TedShifrin Dimension of an algebraic set is defined as the Krull dimension of the coordinate ring.

Comment: Right, I know this; I slightly misphrased. In the non-equidimensional case, can't things go wrong? What if $V=(z-1)$ and $W=(xz,yz) \subset \Bbb C^3$. Then $\text{codim}(V\cap W) = 3$. What is $\text{codim}(W)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin My apologies I misunderstood your first comment! I am having trouble computing the codim of $W$. Any hints on how I can find this? Thanks!

Comment: Well, prime ideals of $R=\Bbb C[x,y,z]/(xz,yz)$ correspond to prime ideals of $\Bbb C[x,y,z]$ containing the ideal $(xz,yz)$. We can get a chain of prime ideals by taking $(z)\subset (x,z)\subset (x,y,z)$, so the Krull dimension of $R$ is at least $2$ (you should be able to see it isn't more). At any rate, $\text{codim}(W)\le 1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see. So this does give an example where the inequality does not hold. Thank yoy very much for all of your help!

Comment: You're most welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first displayed inequality is already false, because in $\mathbf C^n$ you can have disjoint subvarieties of arbitrary dimension: e.g. two parallel hyperplanes.

This is what is behind @TedShifrin's example in the comments: there you have $V$ of codimension 1, and $W$ reducible with components of codimension 1 and 2 respectively. But the codimension-1 component of W is again disjoint from $V$, and this messes up your proposed inequality.

I think the best statement you can get in this situation is something like this:

for an algebraic set $V= \cup_i V_i$, where the $V_i$ are irreducible components, define $\operatorname{codim} V$ to be the minimum of the $\operatorname{codim} V_i$.

Then for two algebraic sets $V$ and $W$, assuming there exists a component $V_i$, respectively $W_j$, of $V$, resp. $W$, of maximal dimension, such that $V_i \cap W_j$ is nonempty, then the inequality you want is true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you possibly give me an explicit example of where my first inequality is false by any chance? (I am confused with codimension of empty set...)

Comment: @JohnnyT.: sure, as I said, two parallel hyperplanes in $\mathbf C^n$ give an explicit example. There are different conventions for what the codimension of the empty set should be, but whatever convention you use, it is always strictly bigger than the dimension of the ambient variety.

Comment: I think I get it now. Thank you very much for all of your help!