# A basic question about closed set in Zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

Suppose I have homogeneous polynomials $f_1, .., f_r \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n]$, and let $I = (f_1, ..., f_r)$. Let $V:=V(I) \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ be the points where $f_i$'s vanish. Suppose $V$ can be expressed as
$$
V = V_1 \cup V_2,
$$ 
where $V_1$ and $V_2$ are non-empty Zariski closed sets. 
Let $V_i = V(I_i)$. Does it then follow that $I_i$ is an ideal generated by homogeneous polynomials $(i=1,2)$ as well?

I am asking this because I was wondering if every irreducible component of $V$ must contain the $\mathbf{0} = (0, ..., 0)$ point or not.

Thank you very much!

PS I would like to add why I asked this question here.
I was learning about codimension of intersection of varieties. In 
[Basic question related to dimension of intersection of two varities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345292/basic-question-related-to-dimension-of-intersection-of-two-varities),
I was pointed out that when $V$ and $W$ are not 
irreducible algebraic sets then the formula 
$$
codim \ V + codim \ W \geq codim (V \cap W)
$$
does not necessarily hold (But it holds true when $V$ and $W$ are affine irreducible varieties that have non-trivial intersection). What I was wondering was that perhaps this inequality holds true even when $V$ and $W$ are not necessarily irreducible in the projective setting. I wanted to prove it, so I wanted to think about the zero sets of homogeneous polynomials in the setting $\mathbb{C}^n$ so that I could apply the inequality where I know it holds true.

Comment: may I ask how you came to consider this question? Usually I only ever think about homogeneous polynomials in the setting of projective varieties.

Comment: Can you do this when $n=1$? If you can, can you convert the question to this case by using the fact that if $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in V$ then so is $(ta_1,\ldots, ta_n)$ for any $t\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @oxeimon sure. It might get a bit long, so let me add it as a PS of the question.

Comment: @Mohan Could you possibly explain a little more by any chance? I get that in the case $n=1$, the only homogeneous polynomials are of the form $x^j$, so my $V = \{ 0 \}$. But I am not quite sure how to proceed from here...

Comment: Let me at least deal with the question of the origin being in all irreducible components. For simplicity, assume $V_1,V_2$ are irreducible. Pick $a\in V_1-V_2$.  Then it is clear that $\{ta\}=\mathbb{A}^1\subset V_1$ and then $n=1$ argument says, the origin is in $V_1$.